# Make div to fadeIn() from a specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have written the below code to move a div to left by 250px and then fadeOut. After it fadeOut on 250px I want it to again fadeIn from it's original position e.g 0px and move left by 250px and then fadeOut. I am working on a single div as an example but basically, I have more than one div e.g. maybe 5 div and I want them to move from left to right and disappear. Then again fadeIn from the original position.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
 setInterval(callMe,100);
});

function callMe(){
 $("div").animate({left:'250px'});
 $("div").fadeOut();
}
</script> 
</head>
 
<body>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<br/><br/>
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want it to fade in at 0px right after it fades out, or do you want it to fade in the next time you call `callMe()`?

Comment: callMe() is automatically call every 100 milliseconds as i use setInterval()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(callMe,2000);
});

function callMe(){
  $("div").animate({left:'250px'}).fadeOut().animate({left:'0'}).fadeIn();
}
```

Try to use chaining in jQuery to accomplish the requirement as needed.

#### [TRYOUT THE FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/v2huq/)

Comment: Both the code examples are working fine but i like it because of chaining. Now new question has been raised when i add another div it's speed is so much that it cross the first div.

Answer (score 0):

check if you want something like this

```
function callMe(){
 $("div").animate({left:'250px'});
$("div").fadeOut();
$("div").animate({left:'0px'});
$("div").fadeIn();
}
```